# Should I cast an object after loading it from serialized form?

Tags: java, serialization, casting

I am loading an object from serialized form:

```
private void loadSerialisedIntersection() throws IOException{
 try{   
 FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream(getPath());

        obj_in = new ObjectInputStream (f_in);

        obj = obj_in.readObject();

        if(!(obj instanceof Intersection)) { 
        throw new IOException("Wrong class");
         }
  }
 catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I was wondering if it is a good idea to cast to the type of object I am expecting? I have seen this recommended but I can only imagine it would cause issues. If this is the right thing to do could you please explain why?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it would cause issues?

Comment: What are you going to do with an instance of Object? Surely you have to cast it in order to actually use it.

Comment: Just incase the object selected was not the right type? but I guess the exceptions would handle that. Sorry I'm very new to the concept of serialization. Do I have to cast the object in order to use it later?

Comment: Yeah cast the object once you load it. Or maybe being safe just check instance of and throw and error if its not

Comment: It won't be much use to you if you *don't* cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast it to the expected type because that is the point of typed languages. You are already checking if that object is a correct instance type. When you finish with ObjectInputStream close it and make obj_in and obj a scope variable not a field (I'm assuming this).

Comment: cheers, guessing the cast should be in the try block and the close() after the catch?

Comment: You are already protecting yourself with the instance type check. Just go ahead and cast it after that.